# Perform segue and don't show "Back" button on the destination view controller

Tags: swift

I would like to seque programmatically to a "setup-VC" when the initial setup is not done. This works, BUT in this case I don't want to show the back button on the "setup-VC".

What I've done till now:

- I've created two VC. (main-VC and setup-VC)

The code of main-VC:

```
...
      if InitialSetupIsDone == true {

             println("Loading the data...") //PPP

        } else {

            println("Segue to setup screen...") //PPP
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueToSetup", sender: self)
        }
...

// Pull any data from the view controller which initiated the unwind segue.
@IBAction func segueToSetup(sender: UIStoryboardSegue)
{
    let sourceViewController: AnyObject = sender.sourceViewController

}
```

- In the main-VC I've created an unwind-segue ("EXIT"-action? - red icon at the top of the VC) and named it "segueToSetup".
- At last point I've connected the "setup-VC" with the "main-VC" while dragging an segue from main-VC (yellow Icon top left) to the setup VC.

Then it would look like this:

[image: http://postimg.org/image/wjcx4jkt3/]

(The upper connection goes directly from setup sign to the "setup-VC")

The goal for me now would be to kind of "hide" the back button in "setup-VC" while the initial setup is not done. Maybe I've don't create the unwind segue right... !? Thx

Answer (score 0):

Write this line in destination VC viewDidLoad

```
 navigationController?.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
```

In viewWillAppaer method also write this

```
  navigationController?.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
```

Comment: Yes, in the VC-main I have only this (before the 3 dots) 

`class VC_xx_main: UITableViewController {

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() `

and in the setup-VC I just have the viewDidLoad (class is declared as UITableViewController)  `override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
       
            self.navigationController?.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
            
    
    }`

Comment: you are define two segue

Comment: Yes. One from the left button (in VC-main) to settings and one from the VC-main to settings. is that not right?

Comment: What I want is: "I don't want to show the back button on the "setup-VC"" thats the major problem.

Answer (score 0):

This disabled the button for me:

```
 let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: navigationController, action: nil)
            navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
```